# Why does my program loop twice?

Tags: fortran, gfortran

I tried to create a toUpper and toLower function in Fortran, and they seemed to work fine in my implementation; the program prompts the user for an input string and then prints it out in caps and then in lowercase.

However, after I added a capitalize function, the program prompts the user for an input string twice, and I can't figure out why. It seems to work, but it does it twice.

Could someone be so kind as to let me know why my program prompts for input twice? Code and output below.

```
program stringutils
    character :: words*1000

    print*, 'Enter a string.'
    read(*,'(A)') words

    call toUpper(words)
    print*, 'toUpper: ', trim(words)

    call toLower(words)
    print*, 'toLower: ', trim(words)

    call capitalize(words)
    print*, 'capitalize: ', trim(words)

end program stringutils

subroutine toUpper(string)
    character :: string*1000
    integer :: i, charNum

    do i = 1, len(trim(string))
        charNum = iachar(string(i:i))
        if (charNum >= 97 .and. charNum <= 122) then
            string(i:i) = achar(charNum - 32)
        end if
    end do
end subroutine toUpper

subroutine toLower(string)
    character :: string*1000
    integer :: i, charNum

    do i = 1, len(trim(string))
        charNum = iachar(string(i:i))
        if (charNum >= 65 .and. charNum <= 90) then
            string(i:i) = achar(charNum + 32)
        end if
    end do
end subroutine toLower

subroutine capitalize(string)
    character :: string*1000
    integer :: i

    call toUpper(string(1:1))
    do i = 2, len(trim(string))
        if (iachar(string(i-1:i-1))==32) then
            call toUpper(string(i:i))
        else
            call toLower(string(i:i))
        end if
    end do
end subroutine capitalize
```

Example output:

```
 Enter a string.
this IS a tEsT!
 toUpper: THIS IS A TEST!
 toLower: this is a test!
 capitalize: This Is A Test!
 Enter a string.
why is this running a second time?
 toUpper: WHY IS THIS RUNNING A SECOND TIME?
 toLower: why is this running a second time?
 capitalize: Why Is This Running A Second Time?
```

I am using gfortran via MinGW in Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is something of an extended comment rather than an answer ...

I'm not convinced by your explanation of the cause of the problem you initially reported.  I can't see why the program would execute twice because of a mis-specified routine or two.  Notwithstanding that, your routines would be much improved by a little more attention to modern Fortran practice.

You've written a bunch of routines to manipulate strings with 1000 characters.  Better surely would be to write them to manipulate strings of whatever length the string passed as argument happens to be.  Modern Fortran (since when I'm not sure, at least 90, possibly before that) allows passing *assumed-length character* arguments, rather like this:

```
subroutine toUpper(string)
    character(*) :: string
    integer :: i, charNum

    do i = 1, len(trim(string))
        charNum = iachar(string(i:i))
        if (charNum >= 97 .and. charNum <= 122) then
            string(i:i) = achar(charNum - 32)
        end if
    end do
end subroutine toUpper
```

Now, when the routine is called it will operate on all the characters in `string`, no more, no less.

There's a host of other modifications I'd suggest too.  I don't have time to cover all of them in detail but if you poke around here on SO you'll find several Qs and As on the topics.  Here's a starter set:

- Always use explicit declaration of program entities, include `implicit none` in your programs (and modules).  This is the fundamental number one rule for writing safe programs.
- Put your routines into `module`s and `use` them.  This ensures that the compiler can, and does, check that the calls you make to them are valid syntactically.
- Personally I'd make all your `subroutines` into `functions` and return a version of the input string made into upper (or lower) case.  There's nothing wrong with having subroutines modify the input string in place but it's easier to compose functions, for example you might one day want to write something like `HumpyString = capitalise(toLower(string))`

Comment: I converted the subroutines to functions and use assumed length character, but it fails to compile. The argument passed still has a length of 1000...


     CHARACTER(*) FUNCTION TOUPPER(STRING)
  CHARACTER(*) STRING
  INTEGER I
  
  DO I = 1, LEN(TRIM(STRING))
   STRING(I:I) = CHARTOUPPER(STRING(I:I))
  END DO
 END FUNCTION TOUPPER

Error: Character-valued internal function 'toupper' at (1) must not be assumed length.

Sorry I don't know how to format this.

Comment: Don't ask questions in comments, they're just too difficult to read.

Answer (score 1):

I have compiled your code with `Gfortran` in Linux.
I have experienced the following :
Your "loop twice" problem indeed happened, but not everytime for me. I got a segmentation fault rather randomly.
I try an answer :

You assumed right, the problem comes from the `capitalize` subroutine. I failed to debug your code with `gdb` but the seg fault seems to indicate you tried to access a component of a string that is not declared or something like that and the fact that you are calling `toUpper` and `toLower` in a loop. That's where I found something:

In the loop, you call `toUpper` or `toLower` by sending them `string(i:i)` which is an unique character (length 1). But in `toUpper`, you declared a character of length 1000 whereas in this routine you are working on  `string(i:i)` only, that is character of length 1, that's not logical. By replacing `character :: string*1000` to `character :: string*1`, it seems to be working and it makes more sense because this subroutine needs to convert ONE character each time.

I can't explain however why your code crashes or loops twice but it might be some kind of memory leak as the result of your character length overflow...

Anyway, @High Performance Mark gives you a good advice about assumed-length character arguments. The compiler may have been able to warn you if you have coded in a way to perform an argument check through modules and interfaces. Perhaps an `INTENT` clause would have been wise. These are powerful features of Fortran 90.

Answer (score 0):

Although I'm not sure what caused it to loop twice, I know it is something with the capitalize function and maybe how I'm sending a single char to a function expecting a 1000 chars. So I added charToUpper and charToLower functions and it works as expected now. Here is the new code. I feel like the capitalize function could be better... comments welcome.

```
program stringutils
    character words*1000

    print*, 'Enter a string.'
    read(*,'(A)') words

    call toUpper(words)
    print*, 'toUpper: ', trim(words)

    call toLower(words)
    print*, 'toLower: ', trim(words)

    call capitalize(words)
    print*, 'capitalize: ', trim(words)

end program stringutils

subroutine toUpper(string)
    character string*1000
    integer i

    do i = 1, len(trim(string))
        call charToUpper(string(i:i))
    end do
end subroutine toUpper

subroutine toLower(string)
    character string*1000
    integer i

    do i = 1, len(trim(string))
        call charToLower(string(i:i))
    end do
end subroutine toLower

subroutine charToUpper(c)
    character c
    integer charNum

    charNum = iachar(c)
    if (charNum >= 97 .and. charNum <= 122) then
        c = achar(charNum - 32)
    end if
end subroutine charToUpper

subroutine charToLower(c)
    character c
    integer charNum

    charNum = iachar(c)
    if (charNum >= 65 .and. charNum <= 90) then
        c = achar(charNum + 32)
    end if
end subroutine charToLower

subroutine capitalize(string)
    character :: string*1000
    integer :: i

    call charToUpper(string(1:1))
    do i = 2, len(trim(string))
        if (iachar(string(i-1:i-1))==32) then
            call charToUpper(string(i:i))
        else
            call charToLower(string(i:i))
        end if
    end do
end subroutine capitalize
```